# How to send AT-command from any microcontroller to telegesis zigbee?

Tags: microcontroller, at-command, zigbee

all
I want to send an AT-command from any microcontroller to zigbee module "telegesis", but I don't know what is the bit representation of the AT-command to be send from the serial port of the microcontroller to zigbee module. 
please any answer will help.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should send ASCII values of A(0x41) T (0x54) followed by Command in ASCII.

Some Zigbee Modules require commands like "+++" or "TTT" to enter in AT Commands Mode.

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty simple. Just connect to the serial port make sure the baud rate is set to 19600. Once you are connected, first test out the connection by sending "AT" which is 0x41 0x54 in binary followed by carriage return which is 0x0d in binary. basically you just need to create a string like this in C

```
char *atCmd = "AT";
```

This will created the necessary streams of bytes which can then be sent via a write() command.

After writing the command on the serial, try reading it via read(). You should get "OK" back